# Doing the integral, possible using some elliptic functions/integrals.

Tags: integration, elliptic-integrals

I have the following integral
$$I=\int_{[0, t]}\sqrt{a+b\sin{\tau}+c\sin^2{\tau}}d\tau$$
By virtue of the transformation $\xi=\sin{\tau}$ the integral becomes
$$I=\int_{[0, \sin{t}]}\sqrt{(a+b\xi+c\xi^2)(1-\xi^2)}d\xi$$
I.e. has the form
$$\int_{[0, x_{1}]}\sqrt{c_{1}+c_{2}x+c_{3}x^2+c_{4}x^3+c_{5}x^4}dx$$
The similar integral, however with a cubic under the square root, may be reduced by a bunch of clever transformations to the complete elliptic integrals, I wonder if someone can see any suitable transformation in this case. Pre-thanks

Comment: If $t$ is arbitrary, then the most you can hope for is an _incomplete_ elliptic integral. But the fact that the polynomial is of degree five suggests that it'll moreover be _hyperelliptic_. (This may still have a closed-form, but if so it'll probably be in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions.)